# Arduino Serial Monitor printing setup output twice

Tags: macos, arduino, arduino-uno, serial-monitor

While working on a project, I found out that the Arduino Serial Monitor was printing the output of the `setup()` function twice.

So, in order to test what was actually happening, I tried it out with the following sample code:

```cpp
const uint16_t MOD = 150;
const uint16_t val = 53314;
const uint16_t m = 30;
static uint16_t count = 0;

void setup() {
  uint16_t A[m][m];
  
  Serial.begin(9600);

  for (int i=0; i<m; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<m; j++) {
      A[i][j] = val % MOD;
    }
  }

  Serial.println("DONE");
  Serial.println(A[0][0]);
  count++;
  Serial.println(count);
}

void loop() {}
```

And found out that every time I upload the code to Arduino it prints the `setup()` output twice.

[image: Sample code execution]

Can someone please provide an explanation as to why this is occurring?

The configuration of the system that I am using to upload the code:

[image: System config]

And, I am using an **Arduino UNO** board.

[image: Arduino UNO board]

Comment: yes it resets twice on USB connection. is it a problem?

Comment: @Juraj I was just wondering why this happens, because if a program has a huge output on Serial Monitor then it becomes difficult to distinguish between the outputs (weather it is a repeated one or not)

Comment: you can add a small delay at the begining of setup()

Comment: Thanks, @Juraj I added some delay at the beginning of the script `delay(1000)` after that, it prints the output once.

Answer (score 1):

Even a delay of 200ms worked for me. Any Lower and I have double prints

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30327965)